# Model Binder not working on first request after App Pool recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with the model binder. Each time after I recycle the App Pool, the first request to the server fails to perform model binding. `Request.InputStream` has the proper request parameters, but the Action parameters are null and `Request.Params` does not contain them either.

This appears to happen on the first POST request with JSON. The real first request is a GET to `Index()`, which returns the view. After that, the client makes an AJAX request that fails.

This is what my Action looks like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetQueryCounters(string query) { ... }
```

This is the contents of `Request.InputStream` on the first request (it's the same on subsequent requests):

```
{"query":"SELECT count(*) FROM accounts"}
```

This is the raw request as seen in Fiddler:

```
POST https://[url]/GetQueryCounters HTTP/1.1
Host: [url]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 281
Origin: https://[url]
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
x-ajaxRequest: true
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
__RequestVerificationToken: [snip]
Referer: https://[url]
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: [snip]

{"query":"SELECT count(*) FROM accounts"}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: never send SQL queries through internet ... you will be hacked in 1 minute.

Comment: This is not an SQL query. It's SQL syntax, but we do other things with it.